# Не работает что то в муSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Вот часть кода:

```
$T_registered_users = mysql_query("SELECT is_login FROM registered_users WHERE is_login = '$_POST[login]'", $db);
$MT_registered_users = mysql_fetch_array($T_registered_users);
if($MT_registered_users['is_login']) $error_login = 'Введеный логин уже зарегистрирован.';
```

Выдает ошибку: 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in X:\home\ua-torrents.com\www\registration\index.php on line 32

Вопрос что за ошибка и из за чего?

Comment: О ужас! 

    ...is_login = '$_POST[login]'

Comment: Почему бы просто не прочитать само сообщение об ошибке? Там ведь ясно написано, что при вызове функции mysql_fetch_array() предоставлен неправильный аргумент, а точнее - не mysql-ресурс. Мы ей передаем результат работы функции mysql_query(), которая возвращает либо ресурс, либо FALSE, и раз мы получаем ошибку о ресурсе, значит, возвращается FALSE. Ищем ошибку в синтаксисе при вызове функции mysql_query и находим $_POST[login] без апострофов.

Читайте текст ошибки, там часто пишется, что и где у вас неправильно.
ЗЫ. И вообще, используйте лучше mysqli или PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите переменные в едином стиле:

```
// before:
$T_registered_users

// after:
$t_registered_users

// best:
$result
```

У вас `mysql_query` скорее всего вернуло `false`.

Необходима проверка:

```
if ($result === false) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Не используйте процедурный подход для доступа к СУБД, ибо **deprecated**. Прочитайте, что написано [в красной рамке на оф.сайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php).

**Как правильно ([почитайте "Почему стоит пользоваться PDO"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)):**

```
$dbname = 'test';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$table = 'registered_users';
$is_login = (int)$_POST['login']; // какого типа данные вы здесь ожидаете?

try {
    //** Соединение с СУБД **//

    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8;", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //** exists **//

    $sql = "SELECT is_login FROM {$table} WHERE is_login = :is_login";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array('is_login' => $is_login));
    if ($statement->fetchColumn()) {
        $error_login = 'Введеный логин уже зарегистрирован.';
    }

} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // display error
}
```